# iframe with YouTube video - Accessibility error: ARIA attributes which refer to other elements by ID should refer to elements which exist in the DOM

Tags: iframe, youtube, wai-aria

I've got an iframe which contains a Youtube video like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/my-video" width="225" height="150"></iframe>
```

When I run the website through the Chrome Accessibility Audit I get the following error within that iframe:

```
[Severe] ARIA attributes which refer to other elements by ID should refer to elements which exist in the DOM (3)
See AX_ARIA_02 for more information.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

==== UPDATE

I've noticed additional errors like:

```
[Severe] Controls and media elements should have labels
See AX_TEXT_01 for more information.
<video class=​"video-stream html5-main-video" style=​"width:​ 225px;​ height:​ 150px;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ -150px;​ transform:​ none;​">​</video>​
```

and

```
[Severe] Elements with ARIA roles must ensure required owned elements are present (3)
See AX_ARIA_08 for more information.
<div class=​"ytp-playlist-menu-items" role=​"menu">​</div>​
<div class=​"ytp-related-menu-items" role=​"menu">​</div>​
<div class=​"ytp-menu" role=​"menu" id=​"ytp-main-menu-id">​</div>​
```

Presumably the Youtube video player isn't ARIA compliant?

Comment: Do you pass the audit if you take out the iframe?

Comment: Absolutely - it's just the code that Youtube puts inside the iframe.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure if you can do anything, it's YouTube's fault after all.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a different approach to embedding the youtube video - e.g. additional flags/attributes or a different url.

Comment: How are you running the audit? If you use its API you can [ignore the YouTube iframe](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools#ignore-parts-of-the-page-for-a-particular-audit-rule). This doesn't apply if you use the browser extension though.